# Using SHA2 keystore for Weblogic 10.3.3 and enabling JSSE=true causes 'too many open files', and CLOSE_WAIT- JVMS stops responding

Tags: weblogic-10.x

We have the following configurations:
WebLogic 10.3.3
JAVA 1.6
Ulimit set to 65K -> maximum allowed by the OS
OS - Solaris 32 bit.

We need to support SHA2 certificate in keystore and we had to enable JSSE=true in Weblogic to do that.
Problem: Nodemanager, Admin and managed server come up correctly but after 40 mins, JVMS have too many CLOSE_WAIT to the Admin server. Then they stop taking requests after couple of hours with growing CLOSE_WAITs.
We applied 3 recommended patches from Oracle docs. Did not help.
Patch1, 2 -> to help JSSE=true to be read
Patch2- 10.3.3 defect with too many open files

can someone please share any more information?

Answer (score 0):

Gave up trying options with WL 10.3.3 and upgraded the entire domain to WebLogic 12.1.3 and JAVA 1.8. Everything works just fine now.